# What is ridin in "We're ridin' with Biden"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What is ridin in "We're ridin' with Biden"?

> > [image]

Source: [[Dantri.com](https://dantri.com.vn/the-gioi/ong-biden-san-sang-cho-le-nham-chuc-dac-biet-nhat-trong-lich-su-my-20210120082832370.htm)]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ridin’ means riding. It is meant figuratively: It does not mean literally riding in the car, just “we are  along with him- we support his candidacy.”

The term for dropping a sound (in this case g) is elision.

“Ridin” has the benefits of rhyming (close enough) with Biden and also having a folksy sound, which is part of the soon to be president’s persona.

EDIT: Thanks to comments by shoover: Ridin(g) also alludes to Biden riding the train from Delaware to DC and the sign is from a transit workers’ unit.

Comment: Maybe also a reference to the fact that Biden lives in Delaware and has commuted by rail to DC for most of his tenure in the Senate? https://www.washingtonpost.com/outlook/2020/10/20/joe-bidens-love-amtrak-tells-us-how-he-would-govern/

Comment: The sign is for the Amalgamated Transit Union. https://www.atu.org/